# What happened to User14 and others

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

On this question [Is it possible to be a Christian by birth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/is-it-possible-to-be-a-christian-by-birth) I see that `User14` is greyed out. I have seen another users greyed out like that on one of my questions.

Were they deleted/banned? If yes, what did they do wrong?

Comment: I miss `User14` and would encourage them to return to the site should they see this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those users have been deleted. The ones you see have all been done at the request of the user, they are not bans or censorship! This sometimes happens when a user decides to quit using the site for whatever reason and wants their name un-associated from their posts.

There are a few users that we have deleted as moderators, but these are spam users for which we will also have deleted their content so you won't see them floating around the site.

If memory serves me User14 was a pastor who decided his time on the site conflicted with his other duties. While we disagreed on some issues, I very much appreciated his knowledgeable input and would have liked to see continue.

As moderators, we don't exactly "ban" users. We can and do sometimes temporarily suspend them if need arises. This action temporarily sets their rep to 1 and disables their ability to post/vote/etc. However their profiles remain viable and a notice on their profile page gives a general reason for the suspension and the date that it will be re-instated. The exact reason for their offense might not be made public, but the action taken would be transparent to the community.

Comment: One more thing to add (although I'm unsure how they appear). Any author may ask to have their post anonymized per the CC-by-SA license under which all StackExchange content is licensed.

Comment: in case of banning a user, does he/she get a warning/notification or it can just happen?

Comment: @tunmisefashipe: As I said, we don't actually ban users. We don't even have a tool to do it. There is a system to temporarily suspend users privaleges. Even that only gets used after they don't take warnings seriously and starts out very short term and only gets longer if they continue after the same bad behavior suspension.

Comment: Thanks Caleb for everything

Comment: @tunmisefashipe to answer the other half of your question, yes, if a user is suspended then they are notified. Moderators have a way to contact users privately for serious issues and this includes the option to suspend an account for a period of time.

Comment: @waxeagle thanks for the explanation. appreciated.

Comment: I've been suspended before.  Now I have access to meta again.